# words splitting to letters when making a list out of them in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to create a list of words or phrases in python 3. For example;

```
a = ('Hello World')
```

when i am trying to convert it to a list, this happens,

```
list(a)

['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

but i want it to be `['Hello World']`

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You simply want to use `[a]` instead of `list(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

a='hello world'
create a list object then add the string object into list object using list built in function
n=[]
n.append(a)
print(n)

Comment: list(a) converts string object into list where each character in a string is stored as an element